# Redirect to woocommerce checkout after adding to cart - item already in cart

Tags: filters, hooks, woocommerce-offtopic

I have this code

```
/*
*   Redirect to checkout after adding to cart
*/
function themeprefix_add_to_cart_redirect() {
  global $woocommerce;
  $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
  return $checkout_url;
}
add_filter('add_to_cart_redirect', 'themeprefix_add_to_cart_redirect');
```

The problem is clicking on a link like `www.example.com/?add-to-cart=1234` will not trigger the `add_to_cart_redirect` hook if there is something already in the cart. It thinks that there is something already in the cart and there is nothing else to add. *Only one of my products can be purchased at a time.*

**Where can I hook in to redirect at an earlier stage in the cart validation process?**

or

**Is there a way to empty the cart before adding the product `1234`?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q: Is there a way to empty the cart before adding the product 1234?**

A: Before adding a product to the cart, it is possible to empty the cart so that the `add_to_cart_redirect` hook will always be called. Use the `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` hook to alter the cart before adding a new item.

```
/**
 * First clear the cart of all products
 */
function clear_cart_before_adding( $cart_item_data ) {
  global $woocommerce;
  $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

  return true;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'clear_cart_before_adding' );

/**
*   Redirect to checkout after adding to cart
*/
function themeprefix_add_to_cart_redirect() {
  global $woocommerce;
  $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
  return $checkout_url;
}
add_filter('add_to_cart_redirect', 'themeprefix_add_to_cart_redirect');
```